# CiviCase Issue when viewing case file

Tags: civicase

I'm having a major issue with Civicase,

Anytime I try to view or search for a case file, I'm getting an error.  I have no problem creating new case files, I have no problem creating new case types, but the minute I try to review a case file I get an error

This is the backTrace

```
#0 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(148): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(997): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#3 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#4 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, 16, (Array:2), " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1925): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(936): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...", "1045 ** Access denied for user 'bvitrave_advisor'@'localhost' (using password...")
#7 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(406): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1231): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#9 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2696): DB_common->query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#10 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1829): DB_DataObject->_query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#11 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(439): DB_DataObject->query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#12 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1599): CRM_Core_DAO->query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...", TRUE)
#13 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php(537): CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subjec...")
#14 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/Page/DashBoard.php(71): CRM_Case_BAO_Case::getCases(NULL, (Array:0), "dashboard", TRUE)
#15 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/Page/DashBoard.php(100): CRM_Case_Page_DashBoard->preProcess()
#16 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Case_Page_DashBoard->run((Array:2), NULL)
#17 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#18 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#19 /home2/blahblah/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(454): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#20 /home2/blahblah/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("case")
#21 /home2/blahblah/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#22 {main}
```

Based on the traceroute, it saying that my SQL username/password access is denied.  But I can't understand why that is occuring only when I attempt to view a case file...Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's because the owner of the database views is a different database user (maybe you moved or imported from somewhere?). CiviCase uses mysql views.

You can disable civicase and then reenable to recreate the views.

Or alter the "DEFINER" directly in the database for the views civicrm_view_case_activity_upcoming and civicrm_view_case_activity_recent.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the issue...everything is back to normal again...MUCH appreciated..